# Canvas on mousemove

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseover

I'm creating some basic animation with JavaScript and I am really stuck. I wanna create animation that draw particles and when mouse go over them it will follow the mouse but every other particles will go random. I don't wanna use jQuery or some of this staff. So far I got this. Can someone give me some hint or advice please? So far I getting error that

> Uncaught TypeError: `particles[i].draw` is not a function.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        particles = {},
        particleIndex = 0,
        particleNum = 250;

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }

    function Particle() {
        this.x = getRandomArbitrary(0, 2000);
        this.y = getRandomArbitrary(0, 1000);
        this.r = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, 255));
        this.g = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, 255));
        this.b = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, 255));
        this.l = getRandomArbitrary(0, 25);
        particleIndex++;
        particles[particleIndex] = this;
        this.id = particleIndex;
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
            this.vx = Math.random();
            this.vy = Math.random();
            this.x += this.vx;
            this.y += this.vy;
            if (this.x <= mousePos.x) {
                particles[this.id].vx = (mousePos.x - canvas.width / 2) / 100;
            }
            if (this.y <= mousePos.y) {
                particles[this.id].vy = (mousePos.y - canvas.width / 2) / 100;
            }
            c.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.r + "," + this.g + "," + this.b + ",0.2)";
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.l, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            c.fill();
        };
    }, false);
    for (var i = 0; i <= particleNum; i++) {
        new Particle();
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        c.fillStyle = /*"rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"*/ "black";
        c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)";
        for (var i in particles) {
            particles[i].draw();
        }
    }, 30);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the particle draw prototype inside the mouse event is no helping. If you don't move the mouse befor you try to draw the prototype will not have the function draw. `Particle.draw` will equal `undefined` which is not a function and thus the error.

You should set the prototype just after you define the Object and do it only once.

```
function Particle() {
    this.x = getRandomArbitrary(0, 2000);
    this.y = getRandomArbitrary(0, 1000);
    this.r = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, 255));
    this.g = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, 255));
    this.b = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, 255));
    this.l = getRandomArbitrary(0, 25);
    particleIndex++;
    particles[particleIndex] = this;
    this.id = particleIndex;
}
Particle.prototype.draw = function() {  
    // rest of draw code
}
```

And remove it from the mouse event

That should stop the error

As there are other problems and I couldn't workout what you were trying to achieve so I added a snippet that may interest you. Along the lines of how I would do it (well how I tell people to do it as it gets very complex to get high performace particles and SO does not give room for that).

```js
// Note this code is in ES6 check browser support if you have problems

;(function() {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const particleNum = 500;
    const particleMouseAttract = 5; // how far the mouse attaction fx ranges
                                    // must be > 0
                                    
    const pMA = 1 + (particleMouseAttract / 100); // alias as I hate long var names in code
    const mouseAttractDistStep = 10;
    const mAD = mouseAttractDistStep; // alias as I hate long var names in code
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    const maxPSize = 10
    const pWidth = innerWidth + maxPSize * 2;
    const pHeight = innerHeight + maxPSize * 2;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', getMousePos); 
    requestAnimationFrame(update);    
    const mousePos = { x : 0, y : 0 }; 
    const rand = (min, max = min + (min = 0))=> Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    const randI = (min, max)=> Math.floor(rand(min, max));
    
    
    const particle = {
        init(){  // call to create
            this.x = rand(canvas.width);
            this.y = rand(canvas.height);
            this.vx = rand(-0.1, 0.1);
            this.vy = rand(-0.1, 0.1);
            this.rad = rand(1,maxPSize);
            this.col = `rgba(${randI(255)},${randI(255)},${randI(255)},0.8)`;
            return this;  // returns referance to this particle
        },
        update () {
            var x,y,mDist,p; 
            p = this;
            p.vx += rand(-0.1, 0.1);
            p.vy += rand(-0.1, 0.1);
            // limit speed
            mDist = Math.max(1,Math.sqrt(p.vx * p.vx + p.vy * p.vy));
            p.vx = (p.vx / (mDist * mDist)) * 2;
            p.vy = (p.vy / (mDist * mDist)) * 2;            

            //paticle to the mouse as vector
            x = mousePos.x - this.x;            
            y = mousePos.y - this.y;
            // get dist
            mDist = Math.max(0.001,Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)); // stop div by zero below
            x /= mDist;  // normalise vector to mouse
            y /= mDist;
            // apply inverted s curve that results in a value 1 for 
            // particles very close (mDist=0) and 0 for particles that
            // are infinitly far. pMA controle the amount of attraction
            // over dist.
            mDist = - 2 / 1 + Math.pow(pMA, -mDist) + 2;
            // mDist is now in the range 0 to 1 with one very close
            // add the random vector and the to mouse vector parts
            p.vx = p.vx * (1-mDist) + x * mAD * mDist;
            p.vy = p.vy * (1-mDist) + y * mAD * mDist;
            // move the particle
            p.x += p.vx;
            p.y += p.vy;
            // keep on the canvas
            p.x = (((p.x + maxPSize) % pWidth) + pWidth) % pWidth - maxPSize;
            p.y = (((p.y + maxPSize) % pHeight) + pHeight) % pHeight - maxPSize;            
        },
        draw () {
            c.fillStyle = this.col;
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, Math.PI * 2); 
            c.fill();
        },       
    }
    const particles = {
        items : [],
        update() { 
            for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i ++){ this.items[i].update() } 
        },
        draw() { 
            for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i ++){ this.items[i].draw() } 
        },       
        add(particle) { this.items.push(particle) },
    }    
    function start(){
        for (var i = 0; i <= particleNum; i++) {
            particles.add({...particle}.init());
        }    
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    function getMousePos(evt) {
        var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); 
        mousePos.x = evt.clientX - bounds.left;
        mousePos.y = evt.clientY - bounds.top;
    }

    function update(time){
        c.fillStyle = "black";
        c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        particles.update()
        particles.draw();
        // get next frame
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    };
    start();
}());
```

```css
canvas {
   margin : -8px;
   border-width : 0px;
}
```

Comment: yea this is exactly what i wanted to create.